# Getting real names out of names that may or may not have a clan tag prefix

Tags: javascript, java, google-sheets, spreadsheet, google-sheets-api

**GOOGLE SCRIPT not just normal javascript.**

I am trying to put together a google sheets to show the rankings for an online videogame, [Cube 2, Sauerbraten](http://sauerbraten.org/). I already have a way to get a list of players on the server at any given moment. However since people join and leave clans all the time, it would be very disappointing if when one leaves and/or joins a new clan, he has to start over in the rankings. So I quickly came up with the below code in hopes to scan a player's name, and if there is a clan tag at the beginning of his name, it gets rid of it. clansPre is an array of some of the clan tags. The idea is that if va|P1, RED|P2, .rC|P3, !s]P4, [RUSS]P5, Crowd>P6, oo|P7, and P08 played a game together, their stats would be recorded under P1, P2, P3, P4, P5, P6, P7, and P08. However, the limited testing I've been able to do has shown that it always removes the first 3 characters, regardless of name. Also, cName was my attempt to get name in string form, back when I was trying to use startWith().

```
var clansPre = ["va|", "RED|", ".rC|", "!s]", "vaQ'", "[RUSS]", "cm|", "Crowd>", "oo|"];
var numClans = clansPre.length;
function nameWoClan(name){
  var cName = name.substring(0, name.length)
  for(var cC = 0; cC<numClans; cC++) {
    if(cName.search(clansPre[cC]) == 0) {
      return cName.substring(clansPre[cC].length, name.length)
    }
  }
  return cName;
}
```

It might be that I'm completely stupid, but in defence, the only programming language I learned that I didn't teach myself was Java, which was last year, and I haven't really needed to use Java since then, so I'm a little rusty. Anyway, thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You were on a right track with your attempt.

However given your code.

`var cName = name.substring(0, name.length)` seems redundant.

Your saying you want the subscription of `name` from the start index of `0` to `name.length` that would be the same as

`var cName = name;`

Now I have written a more complex example that determines if the clan name is part of the name. If it is then removes the clan name but also returns an object with a clan name. Now this method is case insensitive (as it lowers the text). So if you want case sensitive matching then remove the two calls `toLowerCase()`

```
function nameWoClan(name) {
  if (!name)
    return null;
  var clanName = '';
  for (var i = 0; i < clansPre.length; i++) {
    if (name.toLowerCase().startsWith(clansPre[i].toLowerCase())) {
      clanName = name.substring(0, clansPre[i].length);
      name = name.substring(clansPre[i].length);
      break;
    }
  }
  return {
    clanName: clanName,
    playerName: name
  }
}
```

I have done a simple example below.

```js
$('#extract-name').on('click', function() {
  var names = $('#player-names').val().split('\n');
  $('#names-list-body').html(''); //clear the table
  names.forEach(function(item, index) {
    var name = nameWoClan(item);
    if (name) {
      $('#names-list-body').append($('<tr><td>' + item + '</td><td>' + name.clanName + '</td><td>' + name.playerName + '</td></tr>'));
    }
  });

});

var clansPre = ["va|", "RED|", ".rC|", "!s]", "vaQ'", "[RUSS]", "cm|", "Crowd>", "oo|"];

function nameWoClan(name) {
  if (!name)
    return null;
  var clanName = '';
  for (var i = 0; i < clansPre.length; i++) {
    if (name.toLowerCase().startsWith(clansPre[i].toLowerCase())) {
      clanName = name.substring(0, clansPre[i].length);
      name = name.substring(clansPre[i].length);
      break;
    }
  }
  return {
    clanName: clanName,
    playerName: name
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p>
  One full name per line
</p>
<textarea id="player-names" rows="5" cols="65">
john
.rC|sally
[RUSS]Superman
oo|Batman
RED|MAN
RED|va|
</textarea>
<br/>
<button type="button" id="extract-name">
  Extract Name
</button>

<table id="names-list">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Original Name</th>
      <th>Clan Name</th>
      <th>Player Name</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody id="names-list-body"></tbody>
</table>
```

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/bq72xbp0/2/)

**EDIT AFTER REVIEW**

After reviewing the Google Spreadsheet Script (never seen it before). Found we need a few extra bits. First of the `startsWith` does not appear to be supported. Not sure why. So i wrote a simple starts with function.

```
function myStartsWith(name, clanName){
  name = name.toLowerCase();
  clanName = clanName.toLowerCase();
  var cNameLen = clanName.length;
  var nameLen = name.length;
  return cNameLen < nameLen && name.substring(0, cNameLen) === clanName;
}
```

Now I created a sample copy [Copy of Pasta Ranks](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1iK2TXkshOGbq5skk7_16JhAfhqGsyxAfrYAeD4bwhDs/edit?usp=sharing) and have updated the script.

```
function myStartsWith(name, clanName){
  name = name.toLowerCase();
  clanName = clanName.toLowerCase();
  var cNameLen = clanName.length;
  var nameLen = name.length;
  return cNameLen < nameLen && name.substring(0, cNameLen) === clanName;
}

function nameWoClan(name) {
  if (!name)
    return null;
  var clanName = '';
  for (var i = 0; i < clansPre.length; i++) {
    var match = myStartsWith(name, clansPre[i]);

    if (match) {
      clanName = name.substring(0, clansPre[i].length);
      name = name.substring(clansPre[i].length);
      break;
    }
  }
  return {
    clanName: clanName,
    playerName: name
  }
}
function testing(){

  //get the sheet to query
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getSheets()[2];

  //get the last row index
  var lastRow = sheet.getLastRow();

  //get the player names range O2:O18 //removes header
  var range = sheet.getRange(2, 15, lastRow);

  //get the values for the range
  var data = range.getValues()
  var names = [];

  //iterate the range getting the records. note index [0] as values is a multi-dimension name
  for(var i = 0;i< lastRow;i++){
    var name = nameWoClan(data[i][0]);
    if(name)
    {
      names.push(name); 
    }
  }
  var n = names;
}
```

Its not the pretties but if you debug the `testing` function and set a breakpoint on the final `var n = names` you will see `names` contains a list of player names and clan names.

Also worth noting that none of the Player names actually had a clan name so I added `evil.` as a test case.

Comment: Thank you! I think this will help a lot! [Here is what I am using it for](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1ycJ12z3aU7dFOQdnbb6Qtk3qHEUmLe2hifn7PNkdX9c/edit?usp=sharing) switch over to the sheet called "CurGame"

Comment: So it works in normal javascript, but when I put it into google script, it doesn't. It gives "TypeError: Cannot find function startsWith in object vm16". Therefore I am at a dilemma. The support page says to ask a question here, but your answer works beautifully for what I now realize I explicitly asked for. I feel bad doing this, but if I want to get an answer, I need to unmark your answer as the accepted answer. I'm sorry, I feel really bad doing this.

Comment: Understood.. will review google script and update with an answer.

Comment: Thank you for understanding, and being willing to research another language just to help me

Comment: @DylanSchneiderman is have updated my answer and shared a copy of the spreadsheet.

Comment: IT WORKS. I'll have to do more testing, but any more problems will be minor and I should be able to fix those on my own. THANK YOU THANK YOU THANK YOU!!!!

Comment: @DylanSchneiderman glad you got it working. And expanded my knowledge on Google Sheet code.

Answer (score 0):

```js
function removeClanTag(name) {
 var index = name.search(/>|\]|\||'/g);
 return name.substring(index+1);
}

var u = [
 "tag>username",
 "tag|username",
 "tag'username",
 "tag]username",
];

for (var i in u) {
  console.log(removeClanTag(u[i]));
}
```

You could try scanning for the locations of all the tag endings and removing the text from +1 after that point.

If you want to do something more complicated you could create a regex to match specific clan tag patterns like

/[.*]/g

Which will match anything between braces